# Getting a Django project to run with app (eclipse)

Tags: python, django, eclipse

I have generated an app in elcipse using django. I am getting an error when I run it:

```
ImportError: No module named Test
```

I have included the 'Blog.Test', in the installed apps section of settings.py.

Halp! Pls :)

Comment: Are you sure that the modules are uppercase? Maybe case sensitivity is the problem. In my settings I always use lowercase (i.e. 'django.contrib.auth').

Answer (score 0):

See if test is located within app.

`from app import test`

Also, are you sure that you have the folder with a **init**.py that makes it callable.